# hide UIMenuController displays" paste","select","selectAll"

Tags: ios

I am developing an app that supports IM. Below is a `UITextField`, up is  a `UITableView` displaying  historial messages in bubbles（`UIView`）. Bubble has add longPressGesture ,  `UIMenuController` is called by the longPressGesture. My problem is when the textField is *firstResponder*,the keyboad is showing, then `UIMenuController` is called by longPressGesture, normally it works fine. But if there is text in the textField,the menuController show more items than I expected,like "select","selectAll".

Here belows is my code:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copyMenuAction:)||
        action == @selector(deleteMenuAction:)||
        action == @selector(resendMenuAction:)||
        action == @selector(forwardMenuAction:))
    {
        return YES;
    }
   //    else if (action == @selector(cut:)||
   //             action == @selector(copy:)||
   //             action == @selector(paste:))
   //    {
   //        return NO;
   //    }
    else
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];

    return  NO;
   }

  -(BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
   }
```

Comment: can you share some code? Like where are you adding the gesture?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add gesture recogniser only in `UITableView`.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGes = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longGes.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
longGes.delegate = self;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer: longGes];
```

Then in the gesture handler:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil) {
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    }
    else { 
        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer.state = %d", gestureRecognizer.state);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: is your textField is in tableView?

Comment: No,it's not,is there difference?

Comment: Do you need longPress gesture in UITextField?

Comment: YES.UITextField staying the same is the best.